# How do I prevent the terminal line from overwriting itself?

Tags: linux, bash

When I type a long command in the terminal, it starts overwriting the current line I'm on.
In addition, when the terminal is showing a long line, it either gets overwritten or simply cut off.

Below are examples of what happens.

This is what happens when I type a word that is too long, it starts overwriting.

```
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ~ $ bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

This is what happens when I type `ps aux`. The part where it's supposed to say "Application" is cut off to "Applica".

```
root                66   0.0  0.7  4698940 123008   ??  Ss   Thu06PM   4:15.86 /Library/Applica
```

After some research, I found out that non-printable characters have to be escaped by [ and ], so this is what I did in my .bashrc file.

```
//Before
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
PS1='[\u@\h] \w \$ '
export LESS='--no-init'

set -o ignoreeof

shopt -s histappend
HISTSIZE=1000000
HISTFILESIZE=1000000

alias ls='ls -F'
alias la='ls -a'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias mkdir='mkdir -p'
export PATH="$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(anyenv init -)"
```

```
//After
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
PS1='\[\u@\h \w\] \$'     <----- Changed
export LESS='--no-init'

set -o ignoreeof

shopt -s histappend
shopt -s checkwinsize     <----- Changed
HISTSIZE=1000000
HISTFILESIZE=1000000
COLUMNS=250               <----- Changed

alias ls='ls -F'
alias la='ls -a'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias mkdir='mkdir -p'
export PATH="$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(anyenv init -)"
```

I've also set the column size to 250(COLUMNS=250) and made it to check the window size as well (shopt -s checkwinsize), and it's still not working.

Can someone give me an advice on this?

Comment: Please check your file for dos line endings and unprintable characters.

Comment: If you press `ctrl+Q` / `ctrl+L` or type `reset`/ `clear` do you get any improvement? I haven't tried your code but I'd suspect something is changing it unknowingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried all the commands, and I still have no improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is an issue with your terminal in general and not with some commands specifically? I can see two different issues here:

> Below is one of the examples of what happens when I type "ps aux". The part where it's supposed to say "Application" is cut off to "Applica".

Some command such as `ps` will adapt their output to the available screen size when run interactively on a terminal, e.g. by considering the `COLUMNS` environment variable or by getting the available size themselves.

Depending on the command you may force the full output with a respective flag to the command, e.g. with [`ps --cols <n>` or `ps -ww`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#OUTPUT_MODIFIERS), or you can pipe the output through another command, e.g.:

```sh
ps aux | cat
```

Since here `ps` does not output (*directly*) to the screen but into a pipe it will not truncate long lines, `cat` will then output the lines unmodified.

> After some research, I found out that **non-printable** characters have to be escaped by [ and ]

This relates to control characters to use colors for example so `bash` can calculate the correct length of **printable** characters in its prompt. But with your change

```sh
PS1='\[\u@\h \w\] \$'     <----- Changed
```

you actually *cause* a problem here because `\u`, `\h` and `\w` will be replaced by simple text i.e. only _printable characters which `bash` *now* will not correctly count towards the length of the prompt anymore! So you should revert this line.

Also:

```sh
shopt -s checkwinsize     <----- Changed
# ...
COLUMNS=250               <----- Changed
```

Since `checkwinsize` will update `COLUMNS` automatically setting `COLUMNS` here will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! 
Like you said, I reverted the line of PS1, and erased the line of COLUMNS=250. I am however still getting an unexpected result. Below is an example of what happens when I type a word that is too long, it starts overwriting the line I'm on.
`
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ~ $ abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb 
`

`ps aux | cat` worked, the words didn't get cut off. When I tried `ps aux` though, the terminal size was set to max size, and I didn't have any columns environment variable set, so I'm not sure why it was truncating.